# How to use OTA updates in react-native (expo) app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have uploaded expo app in both Playstore and Appstore using `expo build` command to create standalone app. I have not created any release channel. Now I just want to publish new version of app.
It is only JavaScript codes updates. `expo publish` is not working for OTA updates. Any solution ?

Comment: When you restart the app the OTA update should be applied

Comment: ya thats the problem OTA update is not applied

Comment: Have you updated `app.json` since you last built the app?

Comment: I have updated the version in app.json

Comment: Any change to `app.json` requires a new build. If you only changed `version`, you should be able to revert that and try the OTA update again. `version` is only necessary to change if you need to make a new build

Comment: so you mean to say expo publish should work actually?

Comment: As long as the `app.json` matches what you had when you built it, it should